# Prove that the map $L(u,v) := (I+Q)^{-1}(u+v)-v$ is nonexpansive for skew-symmetric $Q$.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, operator-theory, convex-analysis, contraction-operator

I am trying to understand the proof in the Appendix of the paper "Conic Optimization via Operator Splitting and Homogeneous Self-Dual Embedding" by O'Donoghue et al. (link: [https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/scs.html](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/scs.html))

I am stuck on the following part, which I present in a self-contained way here. Define the mapping $L(u,v):=  (I+Q)^{-1}(u+v)-v$, where $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and $Q\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a skew-symmetric matrix. The authors want to show that this mapping is nonexpansive, i.e. $\lVert L(u,v) - L(\hat{u},\hat{v}) \rVert_2 \leq \lVert (u-\hat{u},v-\hat{v}) \rVert_2$ for all $u,v,\hat{u},\hat{v}$. Here the parentheses $(u,v)$ denote the vector $\begin{bmatrix} u\\v \end{bmatrix}$.

In the proof, the authors rearrange terms to show that
\begin{align*}
\lVert L(u,v) - L(\hat{u},\hat{v}) \rVert_2 = \lVert [(I+Q)^{-1},-(I-(I+Q)^{-1})](u-\hat{u},v-\hat{v})\rVert_2,
\end{align*}
and then they proceed to conclude that
\begin{align*}
\lVert [(I+Q)^{-1},-(I-(I+Q)^{-1})](u-\hat{u},v-\hat{v})\rVert_2 \leq \lVert (u-\hat{u},v-\hat{v}) \rVert_2,
\end{align*}
on the basis of the observation that for a skew-symmetric $Q$, it holds that
\begin{align*}
[(I+Q)^{-1},-(I-(I+Q)^{-1})][(I+Q)^{-1},-(I-(I+Q)^{-1})]^\top = I.
\end{align*}

I don't see how the result follows from this observation. Shouldn't the correct thing to prove be the following?

\begin{align*}
[(I+Q)^{-1},-(I-(I+Q)^{-1})]^\top[(I+Q)^{-1},-(I-(I+Q)^{-1})] = I.
\end{align*}

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Let $A=[(I+Q)^{-1},\,(I+Q)^{-1}-I]\in\mathbb R^{n\times 2n}$ The authors are correct: since $AA^T=I$, we have $\|A\|_2\le1$. What you mention at the end of your question is impossible: since $A$ is a fat matrix, $A^TA$ is necessarily singular. It cannot possibly be equal to the identity matrix.

Comment: @user1551 Can you tell me why $AA^\top = I$ implies $\lVert A\rVert_2 \leq 1$?

Comment: The singular values of $A$ are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $AA^T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that
$$
\begin{aligned}
M&=\begin{bmatrix}(I+Q)^{-1}&(I+Q)^{-1}-I\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}(I+Q)^{-1}&(I+Q)^{-1}-(I+Q)^{-1}(I+Q)\end{bmatrix}\\
&=(I+Q)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}I&-Q\end{bmatrix}.\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{aligned}
MM^T
&=(I+Q)^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}I&-Q\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}I\\ Q\end{bmatrix}
(I-Q)^{-1}\\
&=(I+Q)^{-1}(I-Q^2)(I-Q)^{-1}\\
&=\left[(I+Q)^{-1}(I-Q)\right]\left[(I+Q)(I-Q)^{-1}\right]\\
&=UU^T
\end{aligned}
$$
where $U=(I+Q)^{-1}(I-Q)$ is an orthogonal matrix because it is the Cayley transform of the skew-symmetric matrix $Q$. Hence $MM^T=UU^T=I$, meaning that $M$ has orthonormal rows and $\|M\|_2=1$.